# How can I handle PHP Fatal Error in PHP7.1 (PHP-FPM + NGINX)?

Tags: php, nginx

[image]

Here is my NGINX configurations:

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
location = /custom_50x.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
```

However, the fatal error returns with response of 200. Hence it is not caught in NGINX.

I have tried with:

```
try { // Codes that creates Fatal Error here }
catch (Error $e) { throw new Exception('Basically trying to convert Fatal Error into Exception'); }
```

However, the codes above is not stable. Sometimes, it returns with response 500 (which what I want) and sometimes it still returns with response code of 200.

The fatal error happens because the web application is trying to fetch 100,000 objects/rows in a go.

How can I route PHP's Fatal Error from NGINX?

Comment: You would be better off spending time working out how to optimise the code rather than catching the error.  Do you need 100,000 rows, can you process it in parts, can you use the database to limit the data?

Comment: @NigelRen Maybe OP is intentionally trying to catch that error for further work/error handler functionality?

Comment: Is the error in question always this out-of-memory error? When you are out of memory, you might not be able to create new objects (like your `new Exception`.

Comment: @Justinas they could be, but IMHO it's worth asking about alternative methods of approaching the problem.

Comment: @Karsten Koop I am not sure if it is specifically out-of-memory error. But the F Fatal Error (as it is displayed in the screenshot) is `Allowed memory size ... exhausted ...`. And the whole operation costs around 1 GB memory.